# RequireJS define() doesn't call callback

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm wondering why...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define('test', [], function() {
        alert('Done') ;
    }) ;
</script>
```

... doesn't work.

I'm using my own Framework which uses RequireJS if available, and calls `define(name, dependencies, callback) ;` for every module loaded that requires another one.
But sometimes modules don't have dependencies, so `dependencies` is an empty array.

Besides I know that...

```
require([], function() {
    alert('Done') ;
}) ;
```

... works fine.

Could you explain me why the first method doesn't work ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything that requires your `test` module? If not, it won't be loaded (executed).

Comment: Yes it will, only once required (see answer from @Simon Boudrias).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until you require the 'test' module, it will obviously not get called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define('test', [], function() {
        alert('Done') ;
    }) ;
    require(['test'], function() {});
</script>
```